# C++: How to run a system command N times (async) and get N execution times back?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I'm new to C++ and have not used any threading in C++ yet. I'm on windows 7 using visual studio 2010.

What I'm trying to do is write a main method that triggers N executions of a given system command and for each execution it is able to acquire the time taken for that particular execution on completion. It would also be nice to know if the command succeeded or failed through getting the return code for that command and as a bonus getting the output back would be nice although not essential initially.

Now I know how to do most of this but given that I need to spawn N executions at the same time and given that each execution is likely to be long running I'm guessing it will need a thread per execution and this is what I'm not sure how to do.

For someone new to C++ threading would you please choose a threading implementation and library that you'd like to recommend and give me an example main method of how to do the above? I will be reading on C++ threading too subsequently (if you have any pointers on resources please let me know). Many thanks.

Comment: For the threads see [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), for calling external programs in Windows see [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: However, in your case, where the threads should return a value, you should probably look into [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. VS can't find `#include <future>` nor `#include <thread>`. What lib does this need? I thought it was already in stdlib?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg & junkie Sadly no threads for VC10 users :(.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small program using the new [threading functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) from C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

std::chrono::nanoseconds run_program_and_calculate_time()
{
    // TODO: Do your real stuff here
    return std::chrono::nanoseconds(5);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 5;

    std::vector<std::future<std::chrono::nanoseconds>> results(N);

    // Start the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        results[i] = std::async(std::launch::async,
                [](){ return run_program_and_calculate_time(); });
    }

    // Wait for all threads to be done results
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        results[i].wait();

    // Print results
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Result from " << i << ": "
                      << results[i].get().count() << " nanoseconds\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `thread`, `future` and `chrono` includes cannot be found in my VS2010. What do I need to get for these?

Comment: Unfortunately the OP uses VC10, which has no C++11 threading facilities. But still +1, of course.

Comment: @junkie Then you have two choices: One is to search for some multi-platform library which have threads ([Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is popular but might be overkill); The second is to use native threads, see e.g. [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Just use boost. Use only the API that is also available in C++. In this way you could easily upgrade your code to use standard facilities when you start using a compiler with C++11 support.

Comment: Thanks JoachimPileborg. That link looks fairly cryptic but I'll take a look. I'll also have a look at boost as suggested by @jons34yp.